# PyTorch Custom Batch Function

Tags: pytorch

Let's say I have a DataLoader

```
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32)
```

I want to define a neural network that can feed forward my custom function. I know in traditional fully-connected network, I could just using its Linear or other already existed functions. And, importantly, those functions can feed with DataLoader and automatically run with batch.

Now I want to define my own function, but I don't know how to write it without for loop. For example (I randomly write some custom function f(x)),

```
def f(x):
    x = np.sin(np.exp(x)) + np.log(x) - 1/x
    return x

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = f
    def forward(self, x_batch):
        result = torch.zeros(len(x_batch))
        for i in len(x_batch):
            result[i] = self.net(x_batch[i])
        return result
```

Or for loop in f

```
def f(x_batch):
    result = torch.zeros(len(x_batch))
    for i in range(x_batch):
        result[i] = np.sin(np.exp(x_batch[i])) + np.log(x_batch[i]) - 1/x_batch[i]
    return result

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = f
    def forward(self, x_batch):
        return self.net(x_batch)
```

Is there any way to get rid of for loop, in order to do parallel calculation on GPU? Cause I think for loop is not going to utilize the advantage of GPU. Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

Basic mathematical operators implemented in PyTorch work with n-dimension tensors out-of-the-box. If you define your `f` function this way, you can feed the whole batch in one go.

In your case you could do:

```
def f(x):
    x = torch.sin(torch.exp(x)) + torch.log(x) - 1/x
    return x

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = f

    def forward(self, x_batch):
        result = self.net(x_batch)
        return result

>>> net = NeuralNet()
>>> net(torch.tensor([[1,2,3]]))
```

If you stick with PyTorch operators (most have a backward function implemented) and don't switch to Numpy at some point. Then you will be able to call the backward pass on your model.

Of course, all of these computations can be carried out on the GPU!

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation! However, I'm sorry that my function is not simply a basic mathematics operation. The function I need to feed forward is a 'quantum circuit' (can  be looked up at https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/interfaces/torch.html)

Comment: From the documentation, it seems you can still use the PyTorch interface to compute the backward pass. In other terms, the functions provided by *pennylane* are implemented in PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

Pennylane provides a torch layer

https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.qnn.TorchLayer.html

Comment: Well, looks like you answered on your own.